# VueJs creating a directive for date format

Tags: vue.js, momentjs

So I'm new to VueJs and I'm trying to create a global directive to format date using `moment.js`. My problem is that the directive is not getting triggered. Idk if I'm calling it right or not.

**dateFormat.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import moment from "moment";

Vue.directive("formatdate", function(value) {
 if (value) {
 return moment(String(value)).format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm");
 }
});
```

**itemList.vue**

```
<span v-formatdate>{{ item.date_added }}</span>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you need [filters](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html#ad) instead of directives:

```js
Vue.filter("formatdate", // function definition here)
```

And in your template, use it as:

```
<span>{{ item.date_added | formatdate }}</span>
```